# Software Serial.h Library not working

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8, arduino

I created a WP8 App. It connects to the Bluetooth and detected it.and the Bluetooth module connected as well. But the data are not coming from the Arduino to the phone :(

error code

```
if(btSerial.available()) {
    Serial.println(distance); 
    btSerial.write(distance);
}
else {
    Serial.println("error");   -> always prints this 
}
```

in the code always the error part is printing in the serial monitor. I have attached the pins in the Bluetooth device to below pins.

RXD - 11,
TXD -  10,
GND - GND,
VCC - 5v,

Please help me why is btSerial.available() is not firing ?

Comment: Please show the code that is used to set up btSerial.  Better - show the whole Arduino code if it isn't too long.

Answer (score 0):

You have the logic backwards.  available() tests whether the Arduino has data in its receive buffer.  It does not test if the connection is ready.  So the overall pattern of a serial program

```
if(someserial.available()) {
  someserial.read... loop to get input
  print stuff received
}
```

To write, just write.

```
//no if's just go
someserial.write("my output")
```

You do not need to wait.  With the two wire serial connection, you have no flow control.  In other words, there is no signalling between arduino and bluetooth transceiver about ready or other status.  Because the baud rate of the bluetooth link exceeds the baud rate of the arduino serial link, you can't really overflow the bluetooth transmit stream.

The bluetooth aspect of negotiating the connection is meant to be transparent to the Arduino.  In other words, your program is the same as if you where using a hardware serial port.  If for some reason, you need details into the connection, there are special byte sequences that allow communication with the bluetooth hardware.